# How to setup different dist folders for prod and test in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In my angular project we have automated the build and deployment to DEV, TEST and PROD environments, We have a special requirement of when creating/building the project for test env (with command ng build --test) we also need to create the build for prod env. So my exact requirement is to create the build for prod also while creating the build for test env.

For e.g. if I run the command ng build --test its should create the files in dist folder for test and proddist for prod files, internally it should run the ng build --prod command while running the ng build --test command

Please help me with idea/sample as how I can do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also update your angular.json file by adding this line `"outputPath": "dist_stage",` in your different configuration, like this:

```
      ...
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "outputPath": "dist/prod",
          ...
        },{
        "staging": {
          "outputPath": "dist/staging",
          ...
        },{
        "development": {
          "outputPath": "dist/dev",
          ...
        }, ...
```

And then build as usual with :

```
ng build --configuration=staging
```

Answer (score 7):

In your `package.json`:

```
"build":"ng build -test --output-path=test && ng build -prod --output-path=prod"
```

Then run `$ npm build`

This will build test build to `/test` folder and prod build to `/prod`.

Ideally, in a CI/CD you should have separate stages for test and prod builds.